# how to integrate a code properly

Tags: c#

My code should be translating a phrase into pig latin. Every word must have an "ay" at the end and every first letter of each word should be placed before "ay"
ex wall = "allway"
any ideas? this is the easiest way i could think of..

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace english_to_pig_latin
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("THIS IS A English to Pig Latin translator");
            Console.WriteLine("ENTER Phrase");

            string[] phrase = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');

            int words = phrase.Length;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < words; i++)
            {
                //to add ay in the end
                /*sb.Append(phrase[i].ToString());
                sb.Append("ay ");

                Console.WriteLine(sb);*/
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start the problem at its core, which is converting an individual word to pig-latin (ie make a function that accepts a word, and returns it's pig-latin version), then when that works perfectly, work on full sentences.

Comment: Stringbuilder is also much faster than doing: myword += "ay". Well, let's say you had 10.000 words. Now it doesn't matter

Comment: The `Piglatin` tag is *not* for this purpose. Please make sure you look at what the tag description is.

Comment: well, that just seems like a stupid thing to call "Apache's Pig" as a "PigLatin" tag, when PigLatin is something very different than what the tag is 'supposed' to be for. i vote PigLatin should be used for the real PigLatin and a new tag be used for Apache's Pig thing. does anyone know how i can vote for my opinion? helpless_engineer, i commend you for using PigLatin in what i think is the correct use. :)

Comment: @ShawnKovac The way to vote for tag changes is to go to meta for the site in question. In this case, it would be http://meta.stackoverflow.com. There, ask a question related to the change you want, including all relevant information, then wait until it's noticed by "someone in charge". It usually happens pretty quickly.

Comment: @Matthew, I actually started the other way around, but to each his own. I created 2 functions, one which parses phrases into words then another which 'pig-latinizes' each word. for my word pig-latinizer, i just reversed the string, then wrote all the rest of the code. but helpless_engineer, i don't think either one is wrong. the point is breaking it into the two tasks at hand: a phrase parser and a word pig-latinizer.

Answer (score 2):

First you need to define your pig-latin rules. your description lacks real pig-latin rules. for instance, English "sharp" is correctly "Pig-Latinized" as 'arpshay', not 'harpsay', as your explanation above explained. (But i prefer to use 'arp-sh-ay' to facilitate reading of PigLatin as well as using hyphens make it possible to reverse translate back into English.) i suggest you first find some rules for Pig-Latin. Your start is a good start. Your code now separates a phrase into (almost) words. Note that your code will turn "Please, Joe" into "Please," and "Joe" tho, and you probably do not want that comma sent to your word-by-word translator.

when defining your rules, i suggest you consider how to Pig-Latin-ize these words:
hello --> 'ellohay' (a normal word),
string --> 'ingstray' ('str' is the whole consonant string moved to the end),
apple --> 'appleway', 'appleay', or 'appleyay', (depending on your dialect of Pig-Latin),
queen --> 'eenquay' ('qu' is the consonant string here),
yellow --> 'ellowyay' (y is consonant here),
rhythm --> 'ythmrhay' (y is vowel here),
sky --> 'yskay' (y is vowel here).
Note that for any word that starts with 'qu' (like 'queen'), this 'qu' is a special condition that needs handled too. Note that y is probably a consonant when it begins an English word, but a vowel when in the middle or at the end of a word.

The hyphenated Pig Latin versions of these words would be:
ello-h-ay, ing-str-ay, ('apple-way', 'apple-ay', or 'apple-yay'), 'een-qu-ay', 'ellow-y-ay', 'ythm-rh-ay', and 'y-sk-ay'. The hyphenation allows both easier reading as well as an ability to reverse the Pig Latin back into English by a computer parser. But unfortunately, many people just cram the Pig Latin word together without showing any hyphenation separation, so reversing the translation cannot be done simply without ambiguity.

Real pig-latin really goes by the sound of the word, not the spelling, so without a very complex word to phoneme system, this is way too difficult. but most (good) pig-latin writing translators handle the above cases and ignore other exceptions because English is really a very bad language when it comes to phonetically sounding out words.

So my first suggestion is get a set of rules. my 2nd suggestion is use two functions, `PigLatinizePhrase()` and `PigLatinizeWord()` where your `PigLatinizePhrase()` method parses a phrase into words (and punctuation), and calls `PigLatinizeWord()` for each word, excluding any punctuation. you can use a simple loop thru each character and test for char.IsLetter to determine if it's a letter or not. if it's a letter then add it to a string builder and move to the next letter. if it's not a letter and the string builder is not empty then send that word to your word parser to parse it, and then add the non-letter to your result. this would be your logic for your `PigLatinizePhrase()` method. Here is my code which does just that:

```
/// <summary>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="eng">English text, paragraphs, etc.</param>
/// <param name="suffixWithNoOnset">Used to differentiate between Pig Latin dialects.
/// Known dialects may use any of: "ay", "-ay", "way", "-way", "yay", or "-yay".
/// Cooresponding translations for 'egg' will yield: "eggay", "egg-ay", "eggway", "egg-way", "eggyay", "egg-yay".
/// Or for 'I': "Iay", "I-ay", "Iway", "I-way", "Iyay", "I-yay".
/// </param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string PigLatinizePhrase(string eng, string suffixWithNoOnset = "-ay")
{
    if (eng == null) { return null; } // don't break if null
    var word = new StringBuilder(); // only current word, built char by char
    var pig = new StringBuilder(); // pig latin text
    char prevChar = '\0';
    foreach (char thisChar in eng)
    {
        // the "'" test is so "I'll", "can't", and "Ashley's" will work right.
        if (char.IsLetter(thisChar) || thisChar == '\'')
        {
            word.Append(thisChar);
        }
        else
        {
            if (word.Length > 0)
            {
                pig.Append(PigLatinizeWord(word.ToString(), suffixWithNoOnset));
                word = new StringBuilder();
            }
            pig.Append(thisChar);
        }
        prevChar = thisChar;
    }
    if (word.Length > 0)
    {
        pig.Append(PigLatinizeWord(word.ToString(), suffixWithNoOnset));
    }
    return pig.ToString();
} // public static string PigLatinizePhrase(string eng, string suffixWithNoOnset = "-ay")
```

The suffixWithNoOnset variable is simply passed directly to the `PigLatinizeWord()` method and it determines exactly which 'dialect' of Pig Latin will be used. (See the XML comment before the method in the source code for more clarity.)

For the `PigLatinizeWord()` method, upon actually programming it, i found that it was very convenient to split this functionality into two methods, one method to parse the English word into the 2 parts that Pig Latin cares about, and another to actually do what is desired with those 2 parts, depending on which version of Pig Latin is desired. Here's the source code for these two functions:

```
/// <summary>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="eng">English word before being translated to Pig Latin.</param>
/// <param name="suffixWithNoOnset">Used to differentiate between Pig Latin dialects.
/// Known dialects may use any of: "ay", "-ay", "way", "-way", "yay", or "-yay".
/// Cooresponding translations for 'egg' will yield: "eggay", "egg-ay", "eggway", "egg-way", "eggyay", "egg-yay".
/// Or for 'I': "Iay", "I-ay", "Iway", "I-way", "Iyay", "I-yay".
/// </param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static string PigLatinizeWord(string eng, string suffixWithNoOnset = "-ay")
{
    if (eng == null || eng.Length == 0) { return eng; } // don't break if null or empty

    string[] onsetAndEnd = GetOnsetAndEndOfWord(eng);
    // string h = string.Empty;
    string o = onsetAndEnd[0]; // 'Onset' of first syllable that gets moved to end of word
    string e = onsetAndEnd[1]; // 'End' of word, without the onset
    bool hyphenate = suffixWithNoOnset.Contains('-');
    // if (hyphenate) { h = "-"; }

    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (e.Length > 0) { sb.Append(e); if (hyphenate && o.Length > 0) { sb.Append('-'); } }
    if (o.Length > 0) { sb.Append(o); if (hyphenate) { sb.Append('-'); } sb.Append("ay"); }
    else { sb.Append(suffixWithNoOnset); }

    return sb.ToString();
} // public static string PigLatinizeWord(string eng)

public static string[] GetOnsetAndEndOfWord(string word)
{
    if (word == null) { return null; }
    // string[] r = ",".Split(',');
    string uppr = word.ToUpperInvariant();
    if (uppr.StartsWith("QU")) { return new string[] { word.Substring(0,2), word.Substring(2) }; }
    int x = 0; if (word.Length <= x) { return new string[] { string.Empty, string.Empty }; }

    if ("AOEUI".Contains(uppr[x])) // tests first letter/character
    { return new string[] { word.Substring(0, x), word.Substring(x) }; }
    while (++x < word.Length)
    {
        if ("AOEUIY".Contains(uppr[x])) // tests each character after first letter/character
        { return new string[] { word.Substring(0, x), word.Substring(x) }; }
    }
    return new string[] { string.Empty, word };
} // public static string[] GetOnsetAndEndOfWord(string word)
```

I have written a PigLatinize() method in JavaScript before, which was a lot of fun for me. :) I enjoyed making my C# version with more features, giving it the ability to translate to 6 varyious 'dialects' of Pig Latin, especially since C# is my favorite (programming) language. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this transformation: `phrase[i].Substring(1) + phrase[i][0] + "ay"`